# Import only one dependency in Java Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I need to make a jar out of my Java project, and I need it to also contain the class files of one of the dependencies, but not all of them. I've used `maven-assembly-plugin` which includes all the files and creates a huge jar, but I only need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.45</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also tried the maven shade plugin but with no result: I somehow end up including all the dependencies or excluding all of them

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org.apache.spark:*</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.google.code.gson:*</exclude>
                        <exclude>edu.stanford.nlp:*</exclude>
                        <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.optimaize.languagedetector:*</exclude>
                        <exclude>info.debatty:*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you want that specific dependency without its transitive dependencies? Or with it?

Comment: @Tunaki with it's dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'provided' for the scope tag of the dependencies that you don't want to include in the final jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>GROUP_ID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ARTIFACT_ID</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And use maven-assembly-plugin to build the jar

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>MAIN_CLASS</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That didn't do it. I'm pretty sure it's not as easy as setting the scope for the dependency.

Comment: What? This doesn't answer the question at all. Do you know what `provided` means? Furthermore, it is abusing the scope.

Comment: @Tomy Come back and blame after you've actually tried it.

Comment: @KeqiangLi Yeah, I just tried and you're right, it works. My bad :)

Comment: @Tunaki So, provided can be used when JDK is gonna provide the class for you, which means it can be used when you gonna provide the class, this happens a lot if you're writing a plugin, the library is only needed when compile.

Comment: @Tunaki So when you saw there's another post giving the same answer and  you deleted your comment of 'It's a abuse of scope'? Do you know the meaning of 'abuse', I doubt it.

Comment: Nope, but as you said yourself, this is a duplicate question, one that you should flag as duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: @Tunaki If I had known it's duplicate, I would have done that for sure. I'm not that kind of guy wandering around and down voting everything just because he doesn't know the answer or just being bold. If I know the answer, I would always first answer it since it doesn't hurt because it's the right answer. Are you saying you've never answered a question which already have an answer somewhere on this site?

Comment: @Tunaki And you know what the funny part is? You're flagging this question as a duplicate as a question solved the SAME way I suggested, which in your words, is an abuse of using scope. So it's no more abuse? I don't understand what you were trying to do. Confused by your words.

Comment: For what it's worth the downvote was based on your initial version which was unclear, and it was solved by your subsequent edit. (didn't notice the edit until now). And also *If I know the answer, I would always first answer it since it doesn't hurt because it's the right answer* actually, it does hurt [refer to this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316682/1743880).

Comment: @Tunaki I'm totally fine with marking this question as a duplicate, and I'm fine with people down voting my answer since I answered a duplicate question. These things are just fine. But I don't think it's cool that you, without having tried anything, said it was an abuse of using tag 'scope'. And the question you asked me 'Do you know what `provided` means?', I don't think it's cool either. Maybe that's a question that you should ask yourself.